# defaultdict with a parameter to the class constructor

Tags: python, collections, dictionary, python-3.x

[Python 3.1]

I want `defaultdict(int)`, except I'd like the default value to be `1` rather than `0`.

1. Is there any neat way to do that?
2. Should I do that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
>>> def f():
        return 1
>>> a = defaultdict(f)
>>> a[1]
1
```

Here is an other implementation using lambda expression (from **kindall**):

```
>>> a = defaultdict(lambda: 1)
```

Comment: or `a = defaultdict(lambda: 1)`

Answer (score 4):

```
defaultdict(lambda: 1)
```

eg

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> a = defaultdict(lambda: 1)
>>> a["foo"] += 1
>>> a["foo"]
2
```

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:

The function int() which always returns zero is just a special case of constant functions. A faster and more flexible way to create constant functions is to use itertools.repeat() which can supply any constant value (not just zero):

```
>>> def constant_factory(value):
...     return itertools.repeat(value).next
>>> d = defaultdict(constant_factory('<missing>'))
>>> d.update(name='John', action='ran')
>>> '%(name)s %(action)s to %(object)s' % d
'John ran to <missing>'
```

Comment: I happened to have read that in the docs recently and couldn't believe they suggested using `itertools.repeat()` when a trivial `lambda` as @gnibbler suggests works just as well, is simpler, and entails a lot less overhead -- talk about overkill...

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure. Maybe there's a performance gain, I'll test it later

Comment: I am happy to see a lambda-less alternative.

Comment: `def constant_factory(value):return value` is also lambda-less

Comment: @JohnLaRooy to use that you would have to wrap it in a partial function, which probably has the most overhead out of all the suggestions.

Comment: Doh. I obviously didn't have my coffee before I wrote that. Of course I was _thinking_ of something like this closure `def constant_factory(value):def f():return value return f` which can't be written on one line, but equivalent to  `def constant_factory(value):return lambda: value` if I weren't trying to avoid lambda :)

Comment: @JohnLaRooy ; sorry to ask very late, but could you explain why "return value" would not work and you'd have to "encapsulate" one function in another to make it work?

Comment: @AndoJurai, the defaultdict _calls_ whatever you've provided as the argument with no arguments, so it has to be callable. Types such as `int`, `str`, `list`, `dict` are all callable (eg try `int()`). You can also use a function of course, or an instance with a `__call__` method

Comment: @JohnLaRooy Thanks. I sorted it out actually, I can indeed make a direct "def function(): return whatever I want" definition, the catch is having something callable indeed;)

Answer (score 0):

With partial you can create a function with default parameters:

```
from functools import partial
from collections import defaultdict

int1 = partial(int, 1)
mydict = defaultdict(int1)
mydict[1]
```

And a class behaves like a function that creates object.

Also keyword parameters can be used, ex.:

```
from functools import partial
from collections import defaultdict

class Rectangle:

   def __init__(x, y, l=10, h=20):
      self.x = x
      self.y = y
      self.l = l
      self.h = h

TopSquare30 = partial(Rectangle, 0, 0, l=30, h=30)

rectangles = defaultdict(TopSquare30)
john_square = rectangles['john']
paul_square = rectangles['paul']
```

Note that here the default parameters will have always the values given in the moment of the execution of `partial`.

The other answers with lambda or functions will use the value they calculate in the moment of object creation.